# How to use multiline textview with scrollbars in monodevelop/monoandroid

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am new in monodevelop/monoandroid.I need code for showing multiline text in textview I have tried bellow but still its not working.I think there should be some code that I have to include in .cs file,but I am not getting what to use there.
I have used c# code also but its not working. I think ellipsize is a android attribute thats why its not working.Please give me some solution.

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_policy1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Terms of Service O-job Information Terms of Service O-job Information Terms of Service O-job Information Terms of Service O-job Information for Personal non-commercialaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa use only sdfjkj asdfjklfj sdfjkljdf sdfjkljflkj sdfskjfkl sdfjklsdjf sdfkljsdklfj sdfjhsdkfh"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:maxLines="3" 
                    android:singleLine="false" 
                    android:textSize="14dip" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

[image: I want to show textview like]

Please advice....
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
<ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout>

          <TextView/>

          <TextView/>

    <RelativeLayout/>

<ScrollView/>
```

Then you can use the align methods given in a RelativeLayout.

Edit:

Explain what your problem is! Do you get an error when compiling or is the text not shown properly? Be more specific.

Also, why do you use attributes like : `android:maxLines="3"` or `android:singleLine="false"` or `android:layout_height="60dip"` in your TextView. Translated this means: The text must have more than one line but a maximum of 3. Also it can't be longer than 60dip.

Depending on the Text that are very strict rules. Use these rules `android:layout_width="match_parent"` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to make sure that the text can be displayed correctly, remove the attributes I mentioned before in your TextView.

Comment: I have used scrollview also...but I am already using one scrollview in which there are lot of textviews,editexts etc...and in that scrollview one more scrollview is not working,why?...can you please elaborate your answer???

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not working"? `ScrollView` can only hold one direct child. So you need another parent layout inside the `ScrollView`, e.g `RelativeLayout` (You can also use `LinearLayout`)

Comment: Okay one last time, you have to tell us what happens when you compile or execute your code that you have.
If you change what I said the code works and you have a scrollview.

If there is an error in your code we are here to help you. But the code is fine like that, and we are not here to write your code. 

For ScrollView in ScrollView read [this](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling-problem/)

Stackoverflow is a community which helps you to solve **specific** errors. Do some research, try different methods and if you have an specific error, ask.